# how to call >net web service from android log in page

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am new to android development. I am quite learning things faster.

I need code for Calling web service for my Login Screen in Android, ie. when user enters his username and password in the login screen, call web service and check if the user is valid or not from my server and dispaly an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party library such as KSOAP

You can find a easy tutorial here
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

Comment: I use KSOAP library, But how can i pass parameters username and password....my web service URL is http://localhost/MobileLoginservice/Service.asmx.